# Android Studio Align LabelText and EditText Fail

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to make one app with Android Studio but I have a problem.

When I try to add one EditText aligned with one MediumText, that fails.

**Android studio View:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MINOE.png]

**Phone application view :**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcVaF.png]

**This is my layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="oom.dietestat.MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="69dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView" />
```

I have never encountered this problem before.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would something like that : http://i.stack.imgur.com/K6gOd.png

Comment: Please post the XML for your layout.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/B0YZTg86

Comment: Add your xml file to your question by editting so that people won't need to look through comments and then follow a random url just to see 2 elements.

Comment: I can't add more link, my rep is to low.

Comment: We aren't asking for a link. We are asking for the XML directly in your question. Please edit your original question to include the XML.

Comment: Fixed, I can't add pictures... rep again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Use `android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView"` instead of `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"`

Comment: Thank you ! It's possible to collapse the line with the text ?

Comment: What do you mean collapse the line?

Comment: I'm not understanding. How is your current screen looking?

Comment: The line is not close to the number (sry for my english).

Maybe it's better like that : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/06/1455060916-sososo.png

My screen looks like the first example.

Comment: You can add `android:paddingBottom="5dp"` and then experiment with different values of the bottom padding to adjust the line with the text.

Comment: PERFECT. Thank you a lot.